# Linkedin developer app is not available and login via linkedin is not working

Tags: android, ios, linkedin-api

We have integrated signin via `Linkedin` in our mobile and web apps. We have registered a application on `Linkedin` developer portal. It was working fine but now it's not available. We didn't get any notification for the same.

Due to this we are not able to login via `Linkedin` in our apps. But I can see the development app is still active.
[image]

Comment: Are you using Auth for login Or linked In SDK ? If you get any error then post it with question cause not working does not fulfill a question .

Comment: We have used iOS, Android and Javascript sdk for signin in our respective apps.

Comment: You are saying  your app is not available on console. So i guess you must be getting authorization exception at your end. Well if app is wiped out form console then this makes it a Customer Service requirement .

Comment: It's available on linkedin developer console but not active. Refer to screenshot